# Azure AD: silently get token with particular scope, but get token without this scope

Tags: azure-active-directory

I set up Web Api Application in Azure AD and define some scopes here, also set up SPA Application and give permission to created scopes.
When I login I requested that definitely this api scope included and I need to give permission to it. But when I request token silently with this scope I couldn't find that it has been incorporated in token.
Here request to get token with app scope
[image]
Here what token I get (without my custom scope):
[image]

Could you help me, why it's happening?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`User.Read` is a permission of Microsoft Graph. It recognizes the resource you want to access as Microsoft Graph.

Please remove it when you refresh your access token. Just put `api://{client-id}/access_as_user openid profile offline_access` as the scope.

Comment: It helps, thank you, but I don't understand why I couldn't request similenteneosly scopes which may belong to different apps.